# Couldn't get lock for log file %h/logs/MyAppRemoteLogging%u.log

Tags: gwt, tomcat

When I start my Tomcat 7 instance and try to deploy a .war I get the following error.

```
Handler error
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for log file %h/logs/MyAppRemoteLogging%u.log
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:389)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:225)
```

I tried to set absolute paths in logging.properties.

Can someone tell me the cause of this error or what that "%h" points to ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging error on WAR Deploy with Tomcat7, Apache Wink, and Mongo DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623747/logging-error-on-war-deploy-with-tomcat7-apache-wink-and-mongo-db)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a "logs" folder under WebContent folder. Then  put an empty file in it. That's  because Tomcat does not deploy empty folders.