# Logging error on WAR Deploy with Tomcat7, Apache Wink, and Mongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb, ubuntu, tomcat7, slf4j

I am having problems deploying my application onto my tomcat server. I get the following trace every time I deploy it:

```
27-Oct-2013 17:02:34 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/JsonTest.war
Handler error
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for %h/java%u.log
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:389)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:225)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:521)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:464)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager$2.run(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:377)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager$2.run(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:373)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.getClassLoaderInfo(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:373)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.getLogger(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:223)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:381)
at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:310)
at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:341)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:170)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.getLogger(ContainerBase.java:446)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1467)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Server context:

- Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS 32-bit (I'll make it 64 later..)
- Tomcat 7 (only thing modified from stock install is adding users for manager[-gui])
- Java

  ```
  $ java -version
  java version "1.6.0_27"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
  OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
  ```

Application context:

I'm trying to convert the simple "books REST application" outlined [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-useapachewink/) to use a Mongo connection. I have a feeling the Mongo part is irrelevant here. I'm also using Maven and Eclipse to deploy/build the project.

Some files:

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <!-- Project detailes -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.navatwo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsontest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test JSON Marshalling</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>JsonTest</finalName>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>tomcat-server</server>
                    <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!-- Dependency on Wink SDK library -->
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-component-test-support</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongojack</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongojack</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-RC5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

BookWebApp.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package org.navatwo.jsontest;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class BookWebApp extends Application {

    private Logger log;

    private static class AppModule extends AbstractModule {

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see com.google.inject.AbstractModule#configure()
         */
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(BookService.class).to(BookServiceImpl.class);

            // MONGO
            try {
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");

                bind(MongoClient.class).toInstance(mongoClient);
                bind(DB.class).toInstance(mongoClient.getDB("db"));
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("AppModule#configure threw UnknownHostException", e);
            }

            // LOGGING
            bind(Logger.class).toInstance(LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookWebApp.class));
        }

    }

    private Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppModule());

    private Set<Object> svc_singletons = new HashSet<Object>(); 
    private Set<Class<?>> svc_classes  = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public BookWebApp() {
        svc_singletons.add(injector.getInstance(BookService.class));
//      svc_singletons.add(injector.getInstance(JacksonJsonProvider.class));
        svc_singletons.add(injector.getInstance(Logger.class));

        log.info("Started?");

        log = injector.getInstance(Logger.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return svc_singletons;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return svc_classes;
    }

}
```

I don't want to pollute the post with code, so if you think others would be useful, please let me know.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for %h/java%u.log

It looks like Tomcat does not have filesystem permissions to write to the log file. The `%h` variable is the value of the `user.home` system property, which is usually the home directory of the system user running the Tomcat process. Make sure that Tomcat has write permissions to that directory.

The location of that directoy can vary, but you can find it programmatically with:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

You can also modify the default value by providing the argument `-Duser.home=/your/path` to the Tomcat startup script.

Comment: I'll check this later, I apologize, I am not within access to the machine right now.